# I am having an issue with <method range of object _global failed> error

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel VBA and I am working on a project which prints a report.
I am getting an error when I run this excel VBA code. The error is at the "Columnoffset" line
any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
Workbooks(MainWbName).Worksheets("DATA").Activate

rowoffset = DataRow - 1

' Activate WORKBOOK
Workbooks(MainWbName).Activate

Dim ColumnRangeName As String
Dim ColumnDefRange As Object
tabletouse = "ColumnDefinitions"
Sheettouse = "ColumnDefs"
Set ColumnDefRange = Worksheets(Sheettouse).Range(tabletouse)

If FieldTitle = " " Then Exit For

ColumnRangeName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FieldTitle, ColumnDefRange, 2, False)   

Columnoffset = Range(ColumnRangeName).Value   ' <-- Error

Workbooks(CSVFileName).Activate
```

Comment: What is `ColumnRangeName` when the error occurs?

Comment: Hi, ColumnRangeName is "B1InletO2" which is I am looking for but  the issue is getting its value for Columnoffset = Range(ColumnRangeName).Value

Comment: Is that a named range?

Comment: No, It is a variable name. But the value of Columnoffset is returning Empty. I don't know why? Can you help me?

Comment: Your question is unclear: is `"B1InletO2"` a named range in your workbook? If it isn't, you can't do `Range("B1InletO2")`...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are working with `VLookup`, it is best to handle the error in case the lookup text is not found.

```
'
'~~> Rest of your code
'

Dim errorNumber As Long

On Error Resume Next
ColumnRangeName = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FieldTitle, ColumnDefRange, 2, False)
errorNumber = Err.Number
On Error GoTo 0

If errorNumber <> 0 Then
    MsgBox FieldTitle & " not found"
Else
    Columnoffset = Range(ColumnRangeName).Value

    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End If
```

**TIP**: Also avoid the use of `.Activate`. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I am getting the same error even after the error handling still pointing at the Columnoffset = Range(ColumnRangeName).Value

Comment: Then it means that the value of `ColumnRangeName` is not being resolved to a range address. If you feel that the name is correct then check for leading or trailing spaces. perhaps `Range(Trim(ColumnRangeName)).Value`

Comment: It is returning Empty. Do you know why?

Comment: What is the value of `FieldTitle`